# Binding MvvmCross TextColor not work for Android

Tags: linker, runtime-error, mvvmcross

I get the following warning:

- [WARN]  (MvxBind) Failed to create target binding for binding
  TextColor for MvxValueConverterValueCombiner combiner-operation

Binding code:

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/text_view_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            style="@style/text_group_header"
            app:MvxBind="Text DisplayHeader; TextColor AppointmentFeedHeaderGroupColor(StartTime)"
        />
```

AppointmentFeedHeaderGroupColorValueConverter.cs

```
public class AppointmentFeedHeaderGroupColorValueConverter: MvxValueConverter<DateTime, Color>
    {
        private static readonly IDateTimeService DateTimeService = Mvx.Resolve<IDateTimeService>();
        private static readonly Color HeaderGroupBlack = GetColor(Resource.Color.black);
        private static readonly Color HeaderGroupRedLight = GetColor(Resource.Color.red_light);

        protected override Color Convert(DateTime value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != DateTimeService.Now.Date)
            {
                return HeaderGroupRedLight;
            }

            return HeaderGroupBlack;
        }

        private static Color GetColor(int resourceColorId)
        {
            var context = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;

            return new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, resourceColorId));
        }
    }
```

I added the following code in file LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.

```
public void Include(TextView text)
{
    text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
    text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;

    text.SetTextColor(Color.Black);
    var tc = text.TextColors;
    text.SetTextColor(tc);
}
```

It did not help

Comment: Can you add the code you used to bind the TextColor?

Comment: @fmaccaroni, added a binding code.

Comment: To fully understand the issue could you also add the AppointmentFeedHeaderGroupColorConverter?

Comment: @fmaccaroni, added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check that you have installed `MvvmCross.Plugin.Color` in both your `Android` project and your `PCL/NetStandard` project.

Then your converter should be in your PCL/NetStandard project and inherit from `MvxColorValueConverter<DateTime>` so that your color does not depend on your platform:

```
public class AppointmentFeedHeaderGroupColorValueConverter: MvxColorValueConverter<DateTime>
{
    private static readonly IDateTimeService DateTimeService = Mvx.Resolve<IDateTimeService>();
    private static readonly MvxColor HeaderGroupBlack = new MvxColor(0,0,0);
    private static readonly MvxColor HeaderGroupRedLight = new MvxColor(255,0,0); // red_light, should see how to convert this to RGB values

    protected override MvxColor Convert(DateTime value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != DateTimeService.Now.Date)
        {
            return HeaderGroupRedLight;
        }

        return HeaderGroupBlack;
    }
}
```

Finally, use the color converter as you are currently doing:

`TextColor AppointmentFeedHeaderGroupColor(StartTime)`

More info:

[MvvmCross Color docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/color?scroll=1349)

[MvvmCross.Plugin.Color.MvxColorValueConverter.cs](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bdaa09299714d94cf3f2c548a465d994c20d52f0/MvvmCross.Plugins/Color/MvxColorValueConverter.cs)

And here you have the full [LinkerPleaseInclude](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bdaa09299714d94cf3f2c548a465d994c20d52f0/ContentFiles/Android/LinkerPleaseInclude.cs) file provided by MvvmCross.

HIH